# Hibernate many-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have to tables Usuario_tbl and RolUsuario_tbl. I generate java model with hibernate reverse engineering having this .hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="co.ejemplo.modelo.UsuarioTbl" table="usuario_tbl" catalog="structse_db">
        <id name="idUsuario" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_usuario" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="login" type="string">
            <column name="login" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="clave" type="string">
            <column name="clave" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="habilitado" type="byte">
            <column name="habilitado" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="fechaAlta" type="timestamp">
            <column name="fecha_alta" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="fechaBaja" type="timestamp">
            <column name="fecha_baja" length="19" />
        </property>
        <set name="rolUsuarioTbls" table="rol_usuario_tbl" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="login" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="co.ejemplo.modelo.RolUsuarioTbl" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="co.ejemplo.modelo.RolUsuarioTbl" table="rol_usuario_tbl" catalog="structse_db">
        <id name="idUsuarioRol" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_usuario_rol" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="usuarioTbl" class="co.ejemplo.modelo.UsuarioTbl" fetch="select">
            <column name="login" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="rol" type="string">
            <column name="rol" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to save one RolUsuarioTbl using `getHibernateTemplate().save(rolUsuarioTbl)` hibernate tells me that needs all the `UsuarioTbl` properties but I only has setting the login in UsuarioTbl.

How can I save `RolUsuarioTbl` having only login property in UsuarioTbl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many to one relations must be by the code of both tables, otherwise hibernate will not recognize the children of the parent table.